# C++ Singletons: how good is this solution? Advantages/disadvantages, alternatives

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I am working on a C++ project having multiple classes that must be singletons, **with dependencies between them** (order of initialization matters).

I have come up with this solution:

1. All classes which I want to be singletons have **protected constructors**, e.g.:

> ```
> class MySingleton1
> {
> protected:
>     MySingleton1();
> }
> ```

2. Have a source file **singleton_factory.cpp** containing an instantiated class **Singletons** which **derives from all classes which I want to be singletons**, like this:

> ```
> #include "MySingleton1.hpp"
> #include "MySingleton2.hpp"
>
> class Singletons : public MySingleton1, public MySingleton2 {}
> static Singletons s_singletons;
> ```

3. Still in **singleton_factory.cpp**, for **every singleton type**, also implement a specialization of a **getSingleton** function:

> ```
> template<>
> MySingleton1& getSingleton()
> {
>     return s_singletons;
> }
>
> template<>
> MySingleton2& getSingleton()
> {
>     return s_singletons;
> }
> ```

4. The specializations of **getSingleton** will be "hid" under the generic templated variant, in **singleton_factory.hpp**:

> ```
> template <class TSingleton>
> TSingleton& getSingleton();
> ```

Advantages:

- **Low-coupling**:

  - **Singleton classes don't need to be "aware" of the Singletons class**, the only need to hide their constructor under a protected qualifier (and that is not even mandatory, only good practice). The only code actually aware of the Singletons class is **singleton_factory.cpp**
  - Skinny dependencies for **concrete instance**: code that wants to use a singleton of type T **only needs to include the header of type T** and the skinny **singleton_factory.hpp**
- **Order of initialization** can be controlled by **changing the order of inheritance** of the Singletons class
- **No lazy initialization** => **thread-safe**?
- **getSingleton()** is fast, **no dynamic_cast, no reinterpret_cast**

Disadvantages:

- Every time a new singleton type appears, a **getSingleton** specialization, doing the same - i.e. "**return s_singletons;**" must be added to **singleton_factory.cpp**

So, as far as I can see, this is **actually fairly good** so I'm thinking to leave it like this, but I'm **asking for your feedback** (what better place to do that than the programming community?).

What **extra advantages/disadvantages** do you see with this solution?

What **alternatives** do you suggest?

Comment: "I am working on a C++ project having multiple classes that must be singletons"
Must they? What happens if they aren't? Does the world end promptly?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Maybe you should write an article about why the Singleton pattern is useless, maybe you'll get to be famous ;)

Comment: Many people already have. Not so much useless, but it has been pointed out how much of an anti-pattern it really is. https://www.google.com/search?q=singleton+antipattern&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS821US822&oq=singleton+antipattern&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4263j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Comment: Object files are singleton, namespace are singleton => just use procedural programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This forces centralization of Singletons, which can mess up dependencies in more complex projects.  The library that has `singleton.cpp` must depend on *everything needed for every singleton*.  At the same time, anyone who uses a singleton must depend on the `singleton.cpp` library.

Basically your code could only work in a monolithic non-modular project.  Scaling this to multiple dynamic libraries is next to impossible.

Your order of initialization must be maintained manually.

The static global variable's construction point is unsequenced with everything prior to the first expression in `main`.

---

A decent solution I've used is to create a dynamic library that holds the singleton memory.

To be a singleton, you inherit from a CRTP helper, which provides a `::Instance()` inline method.  People wanting the singleton use `::Instance()`.

`::Instance()` creates a static local variable lifetime token.  It then attempts to get storage for the singleton from the primary DLL; if the object is already created, it simply casts the storage into the object type, and increases its reference count.

If not, it creates new storage and constructs the object in it.

At the destruction of the static local variable lifetime token, it reduces the reference count.  If that reference count hits 0, it destroys it *locally* in the current dynamic library.

The lifetime of the singleton is now the union of the lifetime of the `::Instance()` created variables.  Destruction occurs in non-type-erased code, so we don't have to worry about the DLL with the code being unloaded.  Storage is central.  The DLL that stores the storage has to be lower level than every user of the Singleton system, but it in turn has no dependencies, so that isn't a pain.

This is far from perfect; singletons and lifetime are a constant problem, because clean program shutdown is hard and made harder by singleton's existence.  But it has worked so far in a reasonably large project.

Comment: Maintaining order of initialization manually is for me a +, as it gives me precise control, but I guess it can also be an annoyance in some cases. The centralization of all singletons in one translation unit is more of a + for me as well because it enables being aware of the initialization order from a single translation unit. Except for the fact that indeed this poses a problem for dynamic libraries, which is a convincing argument and got me thinking.

Comment: Regarding "the static global variable's construction point is unsequenced with everything prior to the first expression in main." - that's actually the point, the Singletons class _is the enabler of this desired sequencing_ for the singleton classes.

Comment: "clean program shutdown is hard and made harder by singleton's existence" From the Gospel of C++ chapter 98 verse 18. They're a constant source of problems partly because it's difficult to write reliable unit tests for static de-init issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use dependency injection in your case? i.e. have some serialized code create an instance of each class and pass a reference to the instance(s) into the constructors of any other instances that need access to them? This might simplify your design, if applicable. Ideally you could pass a separate, newly-created instance into each constructor to further reduce coupling but it seems you need to share state. In any case, perhaps it helps.

Comment: Could you add any sample? Could you provide more detail about ideas you present?

Comment: yes, but I suggest dependency injection because of its simplicity, M. Franek. There shouldn't be a lot of moving parts. If the number of instances starts climbing then often a refactor can reduce them to a reasonable level.